# Kentico custom table data editing issue

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, kentico

Custom table's data hangs on the loading screen after saving any changes. This is happening on some of tables and it seems that the majority of records are saved, however I have noticed a couple that didn't save within some custom table until reapplying the change!

I was wondering what can cause the issue.

Comment: How big are the tables and how much data are stored for each table?

Comment: There are different table sizes but the one which most of the time has saving problem has less than 20 records!

Comment: Anything weird is happening at the event log at this time? Is insert timing is different from update?

Do you have any custom code running for custom table event like Update? Search your code for something like:  CustomTableItemEvents.Update.

Comment: For size question, more so how much data is in one row? Are you saving binary or a large amount of text? It could be timing out trying to retrieve and that data, or could be nothing to do with Kentico and your host or azure resources are to limiting.

Comment: Consider opening a scripting console using developer tools in chrome while reproducing this issue and see if a JavaScript error occurs.  If the UI hangs it may be a problem in the UI itself, rather than with the database.

Comment: There was not anything weird thing was in event log @Shof

Comment: Thanks @rob-m , I have found the issue in developer tools console of Chrome. There was Mixed context error. I will update the ticket with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue using browser's developer tools.

### Issue

Clicking save button was creating 
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://address' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://address'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` JS error on the browser and browser was blocking the content. However, the form action was not pointing to absolute URL address.

### Solution

As the server SSL config was fine, therefore, there was not any other way than changing core `CustomTableForm.ascx.cs` Kentico file. Although it is not recommended. The problem solved by developing `RedirectUrlAfterSave` property of `customTableForm`object to make sure it will redirect correct protocol instead of Absolute URL

Hope it will help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

This was just brought to my attention, not sure how I missed it before. So, I will post my answer just for the future reference :-)
I guess there is some SLL offloading going on before the actual IIS where Kentico is running. In this case, [SSL Accelerator](https://docs.xperience.io/securing-websites/deploying-websites-to-a-secure-environment/configuring-ssl/ssl-accelerator-support) must be implemented. The link goes to Xperience 13 version but the same idea applies for older versions. Just use the version selector in the top bar - there could be some API differences.

And the same applies e.g. when uploading media files - the browser console will show mixed content warning. This is for security reasons. Browser sees the HTTPS but behind the offloader there is HTTP communication and the GetAbsoluteURL method takes the protocol from the request. Thus, mixed content. Using the ssl accelerator will tell Kentico to use HTTPS internally.